# Steam operation modifying the actual list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have read somewhere that stream operation always return a new collection at the terminal operation and don't change the original collection on which stream operation has been applied.

But in my case original list has been modified.

```
 return subscriptions.stream()
            .filter(alertPrefSubscriptionsBO -> (alertPrefSubscriptionsBO.getType() == AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.PRIMARY_CONTACT || alertPrefSubscriptionsBO.getType() == AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.SECONDARY_CONTACT))
            .map(alertPrefSubscriptionsBO -> {
                if (alertPrefSubscriptionsBO.getType() == AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.PRIMARY_CONTACT) {
                    alertPrefSubscriptionsBO.setType(AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.PRIMARY);
                } else
                    alertPrefSubscriptionsBO.setType(AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.SECONDARY);

                return alertPrefSubscriptionsBO;
            })
            .collect(groupingBy(AlertPrefSubscriptionsBO::isActiveStatus, groupingBy(AlertPrefSubscriptionsBO::getAlertLabel, Collectors.mapping((AlertPrefSubscriptionsBO o) -> o.getType()
                    .getContactId(), toSet())
            )));
```

After this operation subscriptions list has been modified containing only AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.PRIMARY and AlertPrefContactTypeEnum.SECONDARY objects. I mean size of list remained same but values got changed.

Comment: Yes. But you just shouldn't, because the stream API was not designed for this purpose. However, Java does not have a language mechanism to *stop you*.

Comment: Note that this code doesn't modify the original collection: it still contains the same objects. What it modifies s the state of the objects contained in the collection, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are **violating** the contract of the [`map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method:

> **Parameters:**
> mapper - a [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) function to apply to each element

You're violating the "stateless" part:

> ***Stateless behaviors***
>
> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are *stateful*. A stateful lambda (or other object implementing the appropriate functional interface) is one whose result depends on any state which might change during the execution of the stream pipeline. An example of a stateful lambda is the parameter to `map()` in:
>
> ```
> Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
> stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })...
> ```
>
> Here, if the mapping operation is performed in parallel, the results for the same input could vary from run to run, due to thread scheduling differences, whereas, with a stateless lambda expression the results would always be the same.
>
> Note also that attempting to access mutable state from behavioral parameters presents you with a bad choice with respect to safety and performance; if you do not synchronize access to that state, you have a data race and therefore your code is broken, but if you do synchronize access to that state, you risk having contention undermine the parallelism you are seeking to benefit from. The best approach is to avoid stateful behavioral parameters to stream operations entirely; there is usually a way to restructure the stream pipeline to avoid statefulness.

The correct way to implement that map operation is to copy the `alertPrefSubscriptionsBO` and give the *copy* a new type.

Following the style used by the `java.time` classes, e.g. see all the [`withXxx(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#i63) methods of `ZonedDateTime`, you would make or treat the `alertPrefSubscriptionsBO` object as immutable, and have methods for getting a copy with a property changed, e.g. with method `withType(...)` on the class and using static imports of the `AlertPrefContactTypeEnum` enums, you code could be:

```
.map(bo -> bo.withType(bo.getType() == PRIMARY_CONTACT ? PRIMARY : SECONDARY))
```